# How to capture screen activities in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i'm new to windows phone 8 and need your help to capture screen activities in a video. I've to make a video of the activities performing on screen?

one solution to this that strike in me is to capture the screen in image form by dispatching a timer at a instance of time but this is not a right way to do as i've to make a video of screen activities? suggest your opinion how to handle this problem.

Comment: Do you need to do this on the device? Is it part of the application's capabilities?

Comment: Please explain i'm not getting you, which capabilities it need? and yes i want to perform it on device Also can i test this on emulator?

Comment: What I mean is... Is it something you want your users to be able to do when they use their phones? Or is it for some other purpose (debugging, creating a youtube video of your app etc)

Comment: It is for user when the use the application they can record their activities in a video

Comment: Amit - could you explain what you are doing a bit? What does one do/use to perform the capture (before performing the encoding)? (I landed here when searching for Windows Phone Screen Capture).

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way of doing what you want.

You will need two things:

1. Do a dispatch timer as you describe
2. Find code that will encode these frames into a movie. That's not an API that the phone supports - you will need to find existing code and use it. I am not aware of such code existing, but I have only looked for it once or twice and not very hard. You could, potentially, create an MJPG which is a fairly simple video format, but even that's not trivial and the ending file size can be prohibitive.

Comment: Shahar - could you expand your answer a bit?  What does one do/use to perform the capture (before performing the encoding)?